# Renamed plugin folder and when I changed back nothing was activated

Tags: plugins, multisite

To test why a few plugins where not working I had created a new folder and moved 95% of my plugins into that folder named: plugins-null. Well after I visited my site admin and figured out it wasn't any of my other plugins effecting the issues I  went in and used the new folder named plugins-null and just changed its name to plugins and deleted the old plugin folder. Well when I visited my admin area again all of my plugins were there but none were activated. I have a multisite with 89 plugins I would hate to have to reactivate them all.

Am I missing something? Any ideas where I went wrong?

Comment: WordPress probably auto deactivated the plugins when you renamed and visited the site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically when you visit the actual *plugins page* in admin with the folder renamed it will detect this and deactivate missing plugins by updating the `active_plugins` option... otherwise it will leave the option intact and unchanged. At least on single site, I am not fully sure on multisite if anything else triggers this update.

However if you have a backup of your database, you *should* be able to retrieve the `active_plugins` option and reapply it through say phpMyAdmin. Again this may be different for multisite (though I don't think it is, just doing it for the correct table should be all you need.)

Comment: Just to add, for the network activated plugins, they are stored in the wp_sitemeta database table in a row with meta_key called active_sitewide_plugins. And for the plugins activated on each site, they are stored in each wp_X_options table in a row with option_name called active_plugins. The table names might have a different prefix and the X is the site ID.

Comment: Thank you both I am already reviewing our DB backup from yesterday and updating the correct values.